# Display two columns

Tags: c#

This is a SL/WPF application, trying to display two columns.  The following code:

```
MyDomainContext context = new MyDomainContext();
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = context.DBTables;
context.Load(context.GetTwoDataBasesQuery())
```

;

The domainservice.cs contains the method definition as follows:

```
public IQueryable<DBTable>GetTwoDataBases()
  {
    return this.ObjectContext.DBTables;
  }
```

This code works fine but returns all columns in the context
                I need to return only two columns so changed is as follows

```
public IQueryable<DBTable>GetTwoDataBases()
  {
      //trying to return columns
      return GetDBTables().Select(m => new { m.col1, m.col2 });                           
  }
```

But compiler generates errors, does not accept the “return”.

> following error Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable' to
>   'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists.

How to return two columns only?
many thanX

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the *anonymous* type but the return type of collection you have is `DBTable`. You can make the return type `object` or define a new `class` and create object of that class.

*Making object as return type*

```
public object GetTwoDataBases()
{
     //trying to retrun columns
     return GetDBTables().Select(m => new { m.col1, m.col2 });    
}
```

OR, *returning IQueryable instead of anonymous type*

```
public IQueryable<YourCustomType>GetTwoDataBases()
{
     //trying to retrun columns
     return GetDBTables()
            .Select(m => new YourCustomType { YourCustomTypeProperty1 = m.col1, YourCustomTypeProperty2 = m.col2 });    
}
```